# Cant update Windows 11 to next feature release after bypassing CPU check, stuck on Windows 11 21H2

Tags: windows, windows-11

I installed Windows 11 a long time ago and feature updates worked I thought. The CPU fails the compatibility check because it is 7th gen i7. I have TPM. It seems I am stuck on 21H2 and trying to force an update with the ISO for 23H2 fails despite implementing all the usual bypass mechanics. How can I go from 21H2 to 23H2?

edit: I found this : [Update Windows 11 to next feature release after bypassing CPU check](https://superuser.com/questions/1816119/update-windows-11-to-next-feature-release-after-bypassing-cpu-check)

But it applies to 22h2 upgrade to 23h2. Not sure how I can use an enablement package to go from 21h2 to 23h2.

Comment: The CPU fails the compatibility check because it is 7th gen  .... The cpu is to old and your system is not fully compatible with Windows 11.  Nothing much you can to with your existing computer.  Does this help?     https://superuser.com/questions/1659465/will-my-computer-run-windows-11

Comment: You can’t go from 21H2 directly to 23H2 with the enablement package. You can download a 23H2 ISO and run “ E:\setup.exe /Product Server /Compat IgnoreWarning /MigrateDrivers All” and you will be prompted to keep everything and you’ll be able to upgrade to 23H2

Comment: They patched that "/product server" trick. Running either setup.exe or setupprep.exe with those command line options does not work. Comes back with the error that windows setup cannot determine if your PC is ready for windows 11" and offers the close button.